# Sharepoint loading slow -- blank visual web part -- is this normal?

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to optimize an external/public Sharepoint 2013, on-prem site.  Interestingly enough I've found that sandbox visual web parts drastically slow the page down.  I know it's not the code in the web parts, and it doesn't appear to be SQL or the hardware on the Sharepoint WFE.  Developer dashboard shows nothing slow other than the initial page load, so the time to first byte.

To test --

- Set master page to seattle
- Created vanilla sandbox visual web part that says hello
- created blank page
- fired up chrome and looked at network tab of dev tools.  load time to first byte was 200ms
- added one instance of vanilla web part
- load time was about 1.3 seconds
- added 2 more (total of 3) and the load time is now 4.3 seconds

That's insanity.  Is this something with the overhead of sandbox visual web parts, something with our networking for some reason (can't see how as I tested it on the local server and the same stats held true), or what?  I really can't see it being a hardware/resource issue but I'm stumped.  Is this normal?  Anyone else up to giving this a quick test?

In the case where I was trying to optimize, there are 7 web parts and the load time is 13 seconds.  Yeah, so.... that's not optimal.

Comment: For comparison, I added 3 content editor web parts with nothing in them.  Total load time.... 330ms average.  So there's a lot of overhead with a sandbox visual web part it would seem.  Are you kidding?